# How a transfer data from the model in the controller CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

How a transfer data from the model in the controller CakePHP ?

A have a method in model User:

```
public function reminderLogin() {
    $login = $this->data['User']['login'];
    $data = $this->find('first', array('fields' => array('username','email'),
            'conditions' => array('username' => $login)));
    if(!empty($data)) {
        print_r($data);
    }

}
```

Нow to take a $data variable in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the answer by dr Hannibal Lecter:

In your model:

```
public function reminderLogin() {
    $login = $this->data['User']['login'];
    $data = $this->find('first', array('fields' => array('username','email'),
            'conditions' => array('username' => $login)));

    return $data;
}
```

And in the controller action:

```
$data = $this->User->reminderLogin();
if(!empty($data)) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a `return $data;` to get the data in your controller.

Comment: And how it looks in the controller? I'm trying to public function reminder() {print_r($this->data);} // but does not work

Comment: @Saturn: I've upvoted geon's answer which clarifies, but this is really the very basic programming, you should consider doing at least the cake blog tutorial available in the cookbook. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html